# AWS-EC2 - Rails Passenger Page under heavy load

Tags: amazon-web-services, phusion-passenger, ruby

I have an rails app on an aws ec2 (elastic beanstalk) instance. The problem is, when i run blitz.io to test the page load, the page goes into "page under heavy load" at around 100 users. In the past i remembered that you have to change some settings on passenger config to make it work. The server has more then enough cpu and ram power to handle 10k users.

The server is 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.1 running Ruby 2.1 (Passenger Standalone)

Can't seem to find that config on the ec2 instance, also can't remember which setting it was.

Answer (score 0):

After messing with the instance i found out:

change the /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config_healthd.erb
as this changes the passenger/nginx

play with the values:
passenger_max_pool_size, passenger_min_instances, passenger_max_request_queue_size until you hit the sweet spot.